# Can the virtual machine's CPU frequency

Tags: kvm

Can the virtual machine's CPU frequency in kvm be set higher than the host? If you can how to set it up

I want to improve the virtual machine cpu frequency

Comment: This would be a better fit for https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your virtual machine literally uses your host computers resources so you cant give it higher stats than your host machine.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: No you can't `set the Virtual Machine CPU Frequency Higher then the Host`. In fact, you can't set it at all I don't think, but you can "tune" your guest CPU settings to improve performance.

To help solve your issue, please read about `CPU Tuning`

https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsCPUTuning

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/virtualization/ch33s08

Source:

https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2015-September/msg00055.html